# Will React Native's new architecture impact rendering quality?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, cross-platform

A significant difference between Flutter and React Native was that even though Flutter provides better performance, its low-level implementation skips using native code entirely. That means it paints the UI's graphics itself. Because of this, many developers have complained the apps' interfaces gave some "uncanny valley" / unnatural vibes. Scaling for different screens causes weird non-pixel-perfect graphics. Barely noticeable issues, but still..

React Native's approach until now was mapping all the UI Javascript code in the equivalent native code instructions. Will now React Native's own low-level implementation (JSI, Fabric, Turbo) result in the same rendering minor issues of Flutter? Or am I actually confused about how screen rendering works?